# Get Multiple Addresses From Contacts? (ABRecordRef)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, contacts, abrecord

I am trying to get the address of a single selected individual from my contacts.

I am using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and this delegate method to get data like emails and names upon selection of a person:

`- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person`

But how can I get the address of a person (or multiple addresses of a single person should they have more than one)? I need to get each address individually and broken into parts, like address line 1, 2, city, state, zip code, country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here how you get the address property of the person.

```
    - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)
          peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
          property:(ABPropertyID)property
          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

           NSString *string = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, AddressPropertyHere);
}
```

list of address property constants:

```
const ABPropertyID kABPersonAddressProperty;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStreetKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCityKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStateKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressZIPKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryKey;
const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey;
```

Comment: I have tried this: `NSString *street = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);` and its crashes the app. Also, I get a warning saying: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const') to parameter of type 'ABPropertyID' (aka 'int'); ` Lastly, how am I supposed to get multiple addresses like this if one contact have more than one address?

Comment: Use int then instead of NSString.